What is the proof of the mean sampling distribution being approximated by Student's t-distribution?
In the case of non-normal distribution with unknown variance, what is the justification that the sampling distribution of the mean (with large samples) is approximately Student’s t-distribution?
===========================
This is a follow-up on BruceET's detailed answer. It is said that in the case of non-normal data with unknown variance, confidence intervals based on the t distribution are known to be 'robust' against moderate departures from normality.  How is it justified (references are welcome)?

Look here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3240536/convergence-of-students-t-distribution-to-a-standard-normal

With the extremely broad assumptions made here, there can be no proof, because the claim is not true in general unless one is extremely vague about the meanings of "large" and "approximately."  Also, what you know is false: the sampling distribution of the mean of an iid Normal sample is precisely Normal, not Student t.  We need some clarification of what you're really trying to ask here.

@whuber edited.

Thanks.  But now you ask two different questions.  The first asks for justification of a false statement, one that is not equivalent to the second question, which concerns the robustness of the t distribution.  The distinction is that the t distribution applies to the ratio of the sample mean to the sample variance, not the sample mean in itself.

@whuber the question is incorrect but I believe they want to ask whether the convergence of the T-statistic: $T=\hat \mu - \mu / \hat \sigma$ to the Student T distribution is correct. I don't have the time to do the necessary digging but that statement is true (beyond the straightforward fact that both converge to the standard normal) and is a pet peeve of mine. I'll try to do a detailed answer at some point in the near future (TM).

Thank you @whuber. The correct question then would be: what is the justification (for a non-normal distribution) that the ratio of the sample mean to the sample variance converges to the t-distribution?

But it doesn't!  Indeed, I believe it's mathematically impossible for that to happen: if it does converge, it will converge to a Normal distribution.
